# create an extra column based on 16 other numeric columns

Tags: r, if-statement, select, multiple-columns

I have 16 variables that are numeric, and I need to create an extra column that is YES (otherwise NO) when 3 or more variables out of those 16 have a value above 1015.

How could I do that?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `rowSums` :

```
cols <- 1:16
df$res <- ifelse(rowSums(df[cols] > 1015, na.rm = TRUE) >= 3, 'Yes', 'No')
```